# Default array value in Groovy annotation

Tags: groovy, annotations

I have enum and annotation like:

```
enum Permission { user, superuser, admin }

@CompileStatic
@interface Anno {
  Permission[] value
}
```

Now I want to supply a default value to `value`, which should be `[ Permission.user ]`.

I tried different groovy tricks:

```
  Permission[] value default [user]
  Permission[] value default ([user] as Permission[])
  Permission[] value default (Permission[])[user]
  ...
```

but none of them worked, so as a workaround I implemented the annotation in j4v4:

```
public @interface Anno {
  Permission[] value default { user };
}
```

What am I missing?

UPDATE:

The solution was to remove `@CompileStatic` from the annotation.
With `@CompileStatic` the compile threw:

> [Static type checking] - Cannot return value of type java.util.List <io.domain.Permission> on method returning type io.domain.Permission[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a current naming limitation which should be removed but for now you need either:

```
Permission[] value() default [Permission.user]
```

or before you use `user`:

```
import static Permission.user
```

and then your original (with missing brackets added) is fine:

```
Permission[] value() default [user]
```

Comment: the "problem" was in `@CompileStatic`. After it's removal `Permission[] value() default []` worked just fine